# Angular 2 Unused label error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow official tutorial in Angular 2 website. [This tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html)

I'm getting following error in atom IDE:

> Unused label.at line 8 col 1
>
> Cannot assign to 'Hero' because it is not a variable.at line 8 col 7

Following is my code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero = 'Windstorm';
}
```

And the result:

[image: Screen Shot]

What I have done wrong? Help is appreciated.

Comment: by the looks of it hero is a string property in the component yet you are trying to show hero.name in the template.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the tutorial you are referring to, the `hero` field initialization is supposed to be inside the AppComponent:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

Comment: `hero` was initialised in the component. The issue was that `hero` was a string when the template was expecting it to be a object with a property `name`. This is why it didn't work, not because `hero` wasn't initialised in the component.

Comment: @GillesC `hero` object was created outside of the component and without let or var keyword (see line 8 of the original snippet). That caused syntax error even before the rendering, I think.

Answer (score 2):

just keep following the tutorial and you will find the answer a bit later on the page:

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    heroes = HEROES;
    selectedHero: Hero;
    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3